# Java Swt Browser and apostrophe

Tags: java, swt

```
browser.execute("Function('"    + parameter + "')");
```

I use swt to call a function like above.

Using newlines crashed the java.  I just found out using apostrophe crashes the browser.

Is there a better way to do this?  So I don't have to worry about handling these characters?

For example:

```
browser.executeFunction("Function", parameter);
```

What other characters might I have to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by *crash the java*? Do you have a stacktrace?

Did you try by escaping the apostrophe:

```
browser.execute("Function(\'"    + parameter + "\')");
```